# Finding smallest value in a linked list

Tags: c#, linked-list

so i have two linked lists: One which contains items that are required, and another linked list which has a list of items.

So linked list that contains items which are required outputs:

```
    Required item: Automobilis | Amount needed: 1
    Required item: Kirvis      | Amount needed: 2
    Required item: Piesiniai   | Amount needed: 2
```

Another linked list which holds all the items that i have

```
Item name: Automobilis     |  Amount available: 1     | Price of item: 3000
Item name: Automobilis     |  Amount available: 1     | Price of item: 5000
Item name: Rubai           |  Amount available: 20    | Price of item: 80
Item name: Lemputes        |  Amount available: 3     | Price of item: 700
Item name: Piesiniai       |  Amount available: 1     | Price of item: 2000
Item name: Piesiniai       |  Amount available: 1     | Price of item: 1800
Item name: Kirvis          |  Amount available: 50    | Price of item: 100
```

I am trying to sort through the items that are required and the items that i have, see if the names match, if they match i want to add them to a new linked list.

My linked list looks like this

```
  static void FormingNewList(LinkedList<Warehouse> house, LinkedList<Order> order, LinkedList<MatchingItems> match)
    {

        double min = house.First().Price;
        int count = 0;
        foreach (Order ord in order)
        {
            foreach(Warehouse store in house)
            {
                if(ord.Title == store.Title)
                {

                    string nam = store.Title;
                    int am = store.Amount;
                    double price = store.Price;
                    int id = count++;
                    MatchingItems add = new MatchingItems(nam, am, price, id);
                    match.AddLast(add);

                }
            }
        }



    }
```

It outputs:

```
Name of item: Automobilis     |Amount of said item available: 1     |Price of item: 3000
Name of item: Automobilis     |Amount of said item available: 1     |Price of item: 5000
Name of item: Kirvis          |Amount of said item available: 50    |Price of item: 100
Name of item: Piesiniai       |Amount of said item available: 1     |Price of item: 2000
Name of item: Piesiniai       |Amount of said item available: 1     |Price of item: 1800
```

How do i go about only finding lowest price of given item. So for example if i have 1 car which is worth 5000 and another worth 3000 i want to choose the lowest price.

So the desired output would be:

```
Item: Automobilis | Amount: 1  | Price: 3000 
Item: Piesiniai   | Amount: 1  | Price: 1800
Item: Kirvis      | Amount: 50 | Price: 100
```

Comment: `var itemWithLowestPrice = match.OrderByDescending(x => x.Price).FirstOrDefault();` I'm sure this must be a duplicate, still searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you want to group the products by Name then select the lowest price of that item. You can use `GroupBy` to separate the list by item Name, then `Select` the first item from the group after ordering by price (low to high).

```
var SmallestValues = Items.GroupBy(i => i.Name)
                          .Select(group => group.OrderBy(x => x.Price).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Sorry,  but i don't really know how to incorporate this into my program. How i go about even viewing this. If i try to output this  `Console.WriteLine(SmallestValues);`
 i get an error message  `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,ConsoleApp1.Warehouse],ConsoleApp1.Warehouse]`

Comment: @EncoreWLT you would have to replace `Items` with whatever your LinkedList variable name is. You may have to change `i.Name` to `i.NameVariable` and same with Price. This code will create a separate list only containing the grouped items with the lowest price

Comment: Sorry if i am not understanding this, but i have done that  
`var SmallestValues = Warehouses.GroupBy(i => i.Title)
                          .Select(group => group.OrderBy(x => x.Price).FirstOrDefault());`
And i still get the error message

Comment: @EncoreWLT There is nothing wrong with the syntax of that. You can try adding `.ToList();` at the end of the statement (remove existing semicolon) and see if that does anything.

Comment: @EncoreWLT also make sure you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code.

Comment: `foreach(var i in SmallestValues)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }`
I outputed it with this line of code and now it works. Thank you

Comment: @EncoreWLT you should be able to do `Console.WriteLine(i.Title);` (replace `Title` with other property) to actually display the property value(s). Hope this helped!

Comment: Last question, but how do i go about using `SmallestValues` in a method? I want to use it in this method:  `static void BestPriceList(LinkedList<MatchingItems> items, Warehouse SmallestValues)`
and if i try to output it, it displays: 
`Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'SmallestValues' of 'Program.BestPriceList(LinkedList<MatchingItems>, Warehouse)'`

Comment: I'm not sure what the BestPriceList is supposed to do. My code returns a list of `MatchingItems` so you can use each item in the list as the best price list. You don't need an extra method to calculate beyond that.